# Formal name for the coordinate values of the pushforward of the inverse metric on an embedded manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry, inverse, coordinate-systems

What is the formal name of the following object:
\begin{align}\tag{4}
\Delta^{\alpha \beta}
=
\dfrac{\partial y^\alpha}{\partial x^m}
g^{mn}
\dfrac{\partial y^\beta}{\partial x^n}
\end{align}
where $g^{mn}$ is the inverse of the metric tensor
$$
g_{mn} = 
\dfrac{\partial y^\alpha}{\partial x^m}
\dfrac{\partial y_\alpha}{\partial x^n}
$$
and
$$
\dfrac{\partial y^\alpha}{\partial x^m}
$$
is a Jacobian transformation from $x$ to $y$ coordinates. [Willie Wong](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1014330/does-nashs-theorem-allow-an-embedded-representation-of-the-riemann-tensor-witho) states that its related to the coordinate values of the pushforward of the inverse metric on an embedded manifold, however I am unsure if this is the formal name or not.

Comment: If $y(x)$ really is just a change of coordinates, then it's just the components of the inverse metric in the coordinate system $y$.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis Does it change its meaning if the dimension of $y$ is bigger than the dimension of $x$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $y : M \to N$ is a map of smooth manifolds, then your coordinate expression for $\Delta$ defines a "tensor field along $y$" known as the *pushforward* of $g^{-1}$ by $y$, often notated by $y_* g^{-1}$. Thus "pushforward of the inverse metric" is an appropriate name. See e.g. [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_(differential)#Pushforward_of_vector_fields) for a description of the pushforward of vector fields - the situation here is identical in spirit.

Comment: What is a pushforward? Is that a Jacobian transformation matrix?

Comment: @linuxfreebird: in general it's the idea of taking objects on the domain space and "pushing them on to" the target space using the map $y$ in the most natural way. For tensor fields this means applying the Jacobian to each index.