# How does the pushforward of the inverse metric relate to the inverse of the pullback metric for an embedding?

Tags: differential-geometry, physics, inner-products, pullback, pushforward

I am learning some geometry and stumbled upon these two ways to obtain a different metric.

For a smooth manifold embedding $\phi:N\to M$ suppose a non-degenerate, covariant metric $g_{ij}$ on the tangent space $TM$ which induces a pullback metric $g'_{i'j'}$ on the tangent space $TN$ by

$\quad g'_{i'j'}=\dfrac{\partial \phi^{i}}{\partial x^{i'}}\,g_{ij}\,\dfrac{\partial \phi^{j}}{\partial x^{j'}}=[\mathrm J_\phi]^{i}_{i'}\,g_{ij}\,[\mathrm J_\phi]^{j}_{j'}\quad$ (components)

$\quad [g']=[\mathrm J_\phi]^T\,[g]\,[\mathrm J_\phi]\quad$ (matrix)

$\quad g'=\phi^*\,g\quad$ (geometric)

where $\mathrm J_\phi$ is the Jacobian of $\phi$.

On $T^*M$ we have that $g_{ij}$ also induces a contravariant *inverse metric* $h^{kl}$ via

$\quad g_{ij}\,h^{jl}=\delta_i^l\quad$ (components)

$\quad [g][h]=[h][g]=\mathrm I\quad$ (matrix)

$\quad [h] = [g]^{-1}\quad$ (matrix inverse)

Further, on the codomain $\phi(N)$ of $\phi$, this inverse metric $h$ can be [pushed forward](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1310851/formal-name-for-the-coordinate-values-of-the-pushforward-of-the-inverse-metric-o) along $\phi^{-1}$ by

$\quad h'^{k'l'}=\dfrac{\partial (\phi^{-1})^{k'}}{\partial x^{k}}\,h^{kl}\,\dfrac{\partial (\phi^{-1})^{l'}}{\partial x^{l}}=[\mathrm J_{\phi^{-1}}]^{k'}_{k}\,h^{kl}\,[\mathrm J_{\phi^{-1}}]^{l'}_{l}\quad$ (components)

$\quad [h']=[\mathrm J_{\phi^{-1}}]\,[h]\,[\mathrm J_{\phi^{-1}}]^T\quad$ (matrix)

$\quad h'={\phi^{-1}}_*\,h\quad$ (geometric)

where the Jacobian $\mathrm J_{\phi^{-1}}$ can be obtained as the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse ${\mathrm J_{\phi^{-1}}=(\mathrm J_{\phi}^T\,\mathrm J_{\phi}^{\vphantom{T}})^{-1}\,\mathrm J_{\phi}^T}$.

*(**Update: here lies the mistake!** As pointed out in the comments, this definition of the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse does an orthogonal projection w.r.t. the standard metric and not w.r.t. the metric $g$.)*

Now, it seems that for embeddings, this pushforward inverse metric $h'$ and the matrix inverse of the pullback metric $g'$ generally **do not agree** (given I have made no mistakes in my trials where they do agree for diffeomorphisms):

$\quad g'_{i'j'}\,h'^{j'l'}\neq\delta_{i'}^{l'}\quad$ (components)

$\quad [h'] \neq [g']^{-1}\quad$(matrix)

$\quad {\phi^{-1}}_*(g^{-1})\neq(\phi^*\,g)^{-1}\quad$(geometric)

**Q: Which metric, *the pushforward of the inverse metric* or  *the inverse of the pullback metric* is "used" on $T^*N$? (...and what is it used for in physics?)**

On one hand, the pushforward of the inverse metric ${\phi^{-1}}_*\,h$ preserves inner products on covectors from the *reachable subspace* ${\{\omega\in T_{\phi(p)}^* M\,|\,\phi^{-1\,*}(\phi^*\,(\omega))=\omega\}}$.

When $\mathrm P_\phi$ is a projection onto that subspace

$\quad [\mathrm P_\phi]^i_k=[\mathrm J_{\phi^{\vphantom{-1}}}]^i_{i'}\; [\mathrm J_{\phi^{{-1}}}]^{i'}_k\quad$(components)

$\quad [\mathrm P_\phi]=[\mathrm J_{\phi^{\vphantom{-1}}}]\; [\mathrm J_{\phi^{{-1}}}]\quad$(matrix)

$\quad \mathrm P_\phi(\omega)=\phi^{-1\,*}(\phi^*\,(\omega))\quad$(geometric)

then we obtain

$\quad \hphantom{={}}{\langle\, \mathrm P_\phi(\omega)\,,\,\mathrm P_\phi(\mu)\,\rangle}_h$

$\quad =(\omega_i\;[\mathrm P_\phi]^i_k)\;h^{kl}\;([\mathrm P_{\phi}]^{j}_l\;\mu_j)$

$\quad =(\omega_i\;[\mathrm J_{\phi^{\vphantom{-1}}}]^i_{i'}\; [\mathrm J_{\phi^{{-1}}}]^{i'}_k)\;h^{kl}\;([\mathrm J_{\phi^{{-1}}}]^{j'}_l\;[\mathrm J_{\phi^{\vphantom{-1}}}]^j_{j'}\;\mu_j)$

$\quad =(\omega_i\;[\mathrm J_{\phi^{\vphantom{-1}}}]^i_{i'})\; ([\mathrm J_{\phi^{{-1}}}]^{i'}_k\;h^{kl}\;[\mathrm J_{\phi^{{-1}}}]^{j'}_l)\;([\mathrm J_{\phi^{\vphantom{-1}}}]^j_{j'}\;\mu_j)$

$\quad =(\phi^*\,\omega)_{i'}\;({\phi^{-1}}_*\,h)^{i'j'}\;(\phi^*\,\mu)_{j'}$

$\quad ={\langle\,\phi^*(\omega)\,,\,\phi^*(\mu)\,\rangle}_{{\phi^{-1}}_*\,h}\quad$(desirable property 1)

On the other hand, the inverse of the pullback metric $(\phi^*g)^{-1}$ or  ${g'}^{i',j'}$ can be used for raising and lowering indices in invariant expressions

$\quad\langle u,v\rangle_{g'} =u^{i'}\,g'_{i'j'}\,v^{j'}=u_{k'}\,g'^{k',i'}\,g'_{i'j'}\,v^{j'}=u_{k'}\,v^{j'}\quad$(desirable property 2)

I think that both properties, preservation of covector inner products and preservation of invariants when raising and lowering indices are desirable. So currently my questions are

- Is there any advice how to deal with these *two* different inverse metrics on $T^*N$?
  E.g., do we just have both of them and use one for inner products and the other one for raising and lowering?
- Which one is used to define the hodge operator on $T^*N$ then?
- Where else is preservation of the covector inner product necessary?

Edit: I have previously displayed the *pushforward along $\phi^{-1}$* wrong, it is updated to be ${\phi^{-1}}_*\,h$

Comment: What do you mean by $\phi^{-1}$? Embeddings don't generally have inverses.

Comment: That is true. With $\phi^{-1}$ I mean a left inverse such that $\phi^{-1}(\phi(x))=x$, i.e. it is only defined on the image of $\phi$. Its Jacobian $\mathrm J_{\phi^{-1}}$ can be obtained as the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse ${\mathrm J_{\phi^{-1}}=(\mathrm J_{\phi}^T\,\mathrm J_{\phi}^{\vphantom{T}})^{-1}\,\mathrm J_{\phi}^T}$ so one does not need to compute the partial derivatives of $\mathrm J_{\phi^{-1}}$ explicitly. I have used this calculation for $\mathrm J_{\phi^{-1}}$ in the _" pushforward along $\phi^{-1}\;$"_.

Comment: I have updated the question and fixed a mis-spelling of the pushforward along $\phi^{-1}$ to be ${\phi^{-1}}_*$ now

Comment: The pseudoinverse, as you have defined it, isn't well-defined in this setting: the resulting operator will depend on your choice of coordinates. If you want to define a coordinate independent map $T_pM\to T_pN$, you can use the orthogonal projection instead, in which case the two $(2,0)$ tensors do coincide. Also, there's a similar issue taking a pushforward in your definition of "reachable suspace". As a side note, this problem is essentially a matter of linear algebra, so it would be simpler to first boil the question down to one about inner product spaces.

Comment: Thank you for the investigation! Could you elaborate a bit about what you mean by orthogonal projection? I thought that the Moore-Penrose inverse is turned into an [orthogonal projector onto the range of J](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse#Projectors) the way I have it defined ${\mathrm P=\mathrm J\,(\mathrm J^T\,\mathrm J)^{-1}\mathrm J^T}$. Or do you mean, that it does not respect the metric in its projection?

Comment: The Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse is the orthogonal projection with respect to the dot product on $\mathbb{R}^n$, not the metric. Since $\phi$ is an embedding, you can identify $N$ with a submanifold of $M$, and $T_pN$ with a subspace of $T_pM$ for $p\in N\subseteq M$. From there, the orthogonal projection $T_pM\to T_pN$ is just the ordinary one from linear algebra.

Comment: Ah, of course. Thank you for pointing that out! It seems that using ${\mathrm J^{-1}_g=(\mathrm J^T\;g\;\mathrm J)^{-1}(\mathrm J^T\;g)}$ and $\mathrm P=\mathrm J\;\mathrm J^{-1}_g$ makes both properties (1 and 2) provable. I will check this and update the question.

Comment: In general $J_{\varphi^{-1}}  \neq (J_\varphi)^\dagger$, however, it is always true that $g^{-1} = (J_\varphi^T J_\varphi)^{-1} = J_\varphi^{\dagger} (J_\varphi^{\dagger})^T$ I think you are correct that the discrepancy comes from this projection business, but its not obvious to me that your $J_g$ construction is the solution

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in the comments, the subspace projection in $TM$ needs to account for the metric $g$. I have put together a proof on matrix level to see how the pieces come together:

If we obtain the **Moore-Penrose inverse w.r.t. $g$** in the following way:

$\quad[\mathrm J_{\phi\,g}^{-1}] = ([\mathrm J_\phi]^T\;[g]\;[\mathrm J_\phi])^{-1} ([\mathrm J_\phi]^T\;[g])$

$\quad[\mathrm J_{\phi\,g}^{-1}]^T=([g]^T\;[\mathrm J_\phi])\;([\mathrm J_\phi]^T\;[g]\;[\mathrm J_\phi])^{-T}$

then this still makes $[\mathrm J_{\phi\,g}^{-1}]$ a **left inverse** for $[\mathrm J_\phi]$, just as $[\mathrm J_{\phi}^{-1}]$ before:

$\quad\phantom{=} [\mathrm J_{\phi\,g}^{-1}]\;[\mathrm J_\phi]$

$\quad= ([\mathrm J_\phi]^T\;[g]\;[\mathrm J_\phi])^{-1} ([\mathrm J_\phi]^T\;[g])\;[\mathrm J_\phi]$

$\quad= ([\mathrm J_\phi]^T\;[g]\;[\mathrm J_\phi])^{-1} ([\mathrm J_\phi]^T\;[g]\;[\mathrm J_\phi])$

$\quad= \mathrm I$

And when used to *transform* the inverse metric

$\quad  ([g]^{-1})' = [\mathrm J_{\phi\,g}^{-1}]\;[g]^{-1} [\mathrm J_{\phi\,g}^{-1}]^T$ (transformed inverse metric)

then we obtain **desirable property 2:** inversion commutes with transformation $([g]^{-1})' = ([g]')^{-1}$

$\quad\phantom{=} ([g]^{-1})'$

$\quad= [\mathrm J_{\phi\,g}^{-1}]\;[g]^{-1}\;[\mathrm J_{\phi\,g}^{-1}]^T$

$\quad= ([\mathrm J_\phi]^T\;[g]\;[\mathrm J_\phi])^{-1}\;([\mathrm J_\phi]^T\;[g])\;[g]^{-1}\;([g]^T\;[\mathrm J_\phi])\;([\mathrm J_\phi]^T\;[g]\;[\mathrm J_\phi])^{-T}$

$\quad= ([\mathrm J_\phi]^T\;[g]\;[\mathrm J_\phi])^{-1}\;[\mathrm J_\phi]^T\;[g]\;[g]^{-1}\;[g]^T\;[\mathrm J_\phi]\;([\mathrm J_\phi]^T\;[g]\;[\mathrm J_\phi])^{-T}$

$\quad= ([\mathrm J_\phi]^T\;[g]\;[\mathrm J_\phi])^{-1}\;[\mathrm J_\phi]^T\;[g]^T\;[\mathrm J_\phi]\;([\mathrm J_\phi]^T\;[g]\;[\mathrm J_\phi])^{-T}$

$\quad= ([\mathrm J_\phi]^T\;[g]\;[\mathrm J_\phi])^{-1}\;([\mathrm J_\phi]^T\;[g]^T\;[\mathrm J_\phi])\;([\mathrm J_\phi]^T\;[g]\;[\mathrm J_\phi])^{-T}$

$\quad= ([\mathrm J_\phi]^T\;[g]\;[\mathrm J_\phi])^{-1}\;([\mathrm J_\phi]^T\;[g]^T\;[\mathrm J_\phi])\;([\mathrm J_\phi]^T\;[g]^T\;[\mathrm J_\phi])^{-1}$

$\quad= ([\mathrm J_\phi]^T\;[g]\;[\mathrm J_\phi])^{-1}$

$\quad= ([g]')^{-1}$

For the "reachable subspace" projection $\mathrm P_{\phi\,g}$ w.r.t. the metric $g$

$\quad  [\mathrm P_{\phi\,g}]  = [\mathrm J_\phi]\;[\mathrm J_{\phi\,g}^{-1}]$ (projection)

$\quad  [\mathrm P_{\phi\,g}]^T= [\mathrm J_{\phi\,g}^{-T}]\;[\mathrm J_\phi]^T$

we also obtain **desirable property 1:** $[g]^{-1}$ inner product on the projection equals $([g]^{-1})'$ inner product after transformation

$\quad\phantom{=} \langle \mathrm P_{\phi\,g}(ω), \mathrm P_{\phi\,g}(μ) \rangle_{g^{-1}}$

$\quad= ([\mathrm P_{\phi\,g}]^T\;ω)^T\;[g]^{-1}\;([\mathrm P_{\phi\,g}]^T\;μ)$

$\quad= ([\mathrm J_{\phi\,g}^{-T}]\;[\mathrm J_\phi]^T\;ω)^T\;[g]^{-1}\;([\mathrm J_{\phi\,g}^{-T}]\;[\mathrm J_\phi]^T\;μ)$

$\quad= (ω^T\;[\mathrm J_\phi]\;  [\mathrm J_{\phi\,g}^{-1}])\;[g]^{-1}\;([\mathrm J_{\phi\,g}^{-T}]\;  [\mathrm J_\phi]^T\;μ)$

$\quad= (ω^T\;[\mathrm J_\phi])\;([\mathrm J_{\phi\,g}^{-1}] \;[g]^{-1}\;[\mathrm J_{\phi\,g}^{-T}])\;([\mathrm J_\phi]^T\;μ)$

$\quad= (ω^T)'\;([g]^{-1})'\;(μ)'$

$\quad= \langle ω' , μ' \rangle_{(g^{-1})'}$

With these definitions, there is a relation to the matrix $[\mathrm J_{\phi}^{-1}]$ which was the *metric-less* Moore-Penrose inverse

$\quad[\mathrm J_{\phi}^{-1}] = ([\mathrm J_\phi]^T\;[\mathrm J_\phi])^{-1}\;[\mathrm J_\phi]^T$

We have

$\quad\phantom{=}[\mathrm J_{\phi}^{-1}]\;[\mathrm P_{\phi\,g}]$

$\quad= ([\mathrm J_\phi]^T\;[\mathrm J_\phi])^{-1}\;[\mathrm J_\phi]^T\;[\mathrm J_\phi]\;[\mathrm J_{\phi\,g}^{-1}]$

$\quad= ([\mathrm J_\phi]^T\;[\mathrm J_\phi])^{-1}\;([\mathrm J_\phi]^T\;[\mathrm J_\phi])\;[\mathrm J_{\phi\,g}^{-1}]$

$\quad= [\mathrm J_{\phi\,g}^{-1}]$

which hints that our assembled $[\mathrm J_{\phi\,g}^{-1}]$ is the matrix representation occuring in a **pushforward after projection** $\phi_*\circ\mathrm P_{\phi\,g}$ geometrically.

This further suggests to identify "transformation" as the "pushforward after projection".

Furthermore $[\mathrm J_{\phi\,g}^{-1}]$ agrees with $[\mathrm J_{\phi}^{-1}]$ on the reachable subspace.

Any comments?